# How to Generate crystal report in visual studio 2010 WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I want to generate a crystal report in visual studio 2010 in WPF application.

Can anyone please help me to solve out ?

I have tried but it does not works ..

please provide me the code ?

Comment: You say that you tried and failed, please specify what exactly you did and what failed, with what error. In this way we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Report now doesn't comes with Visual Studio. You have to download it separately. Follow this link: http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp .

Once you install the CR2010. You will be able to add crystal report pages (.rpt) in your project using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Crystal Reports are provided by default any more in VS2010, you have to download and install them separately.